# Is it possible to give Highcharts, pie chart, an array of images instead of colors?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have a pie chart with some colors in it. Though I also want to load image patterns as well.

Here's how I have it:

```
 plotOptions: {
            pie: {
                allowPointSelect: true,
                cursor: 'pointer',
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: false
                },
                showInLegend: true,
                size: 200,
                startAngle: 30,
                colors: [
                    {
                        pattern: '../Images/Food_Bolus_Pattern.gif',
                        width: 10,
                        height: 10
                    },
                    '#9D4EFF',
                    '#004B66',
                    {
                        pattern: '../Images/Quick_Bolus_Pattern.gif',
                        width: 10,
                        height: 10
                    },
                    '#CB9A66'
                ]
            }
        }
```

Here's a fiddle as well! As you can see the images do not render on the pie chart. Is this possible? How can I make this possible? http://jsfiddle.net/2n36syny/

Comment: Per the docs (https://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-design-and-style/gradients-shadows-and-patterns) if you are not using the styled mode version of highcharts then you need to use a plugin to get pattern fills (https://www.highcharts.com/products/plugin-registry/single/9/Pattern-Fill).

Comment: These should be SVG paths as well I think - not jpeg files.

Answer (score 0):

I think I've discovered the issue I'm having. Wergeld's comment has helped alot.

What was needed is a highcharts plugin. View [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2n36syny/1/) to see the pattern pluging loaded up to let images be viewed.

```
<script src="https://highcharts.github.io/pattern-fill/pattern-fill.js"></script>
```